# Cache MVC PartialView returned from ajax get

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Is is possible to cache an MVC partial view being returned from an ajax get request?

Here's my scenario. I'm calling a url which points to a controller method that returns a partial view:

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    return View("SignIn");
}
```

Ajax request to get the view:

```
$.get('/Home/SignIn', function (data) { $('.content').html(data); });
```

Is it possible to cache my "SignIn" view so that each time the user clicks it, it doesn't have to go back to the server to fetch the view from the controller again?

Comment: Send the response with far future [expire header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would cache the view on the server - limiting server load -

Change your action to:

```
public class Home : Controller
{
    // You can change this duration to whatever you want (in seconds)
    [OutputCache(Duration = 6000)] 
    public ActionResult SignIn()
    {
        return View("SignIn");
    }
}
```

Your AJAX request remains the same:

```
$.get('/Home/SignIn', function (data) { $('.content').html(data); });
```

Comment: This will cache it on the server, I'm looking to have the view cached on the client in order to avoid making repeated trips to the server when the view's already been served up to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe store the results in a locally declared javascript variable. For instance (pseudo code) ..

```
var PageState = {};
PageState.CachedView = function(){ $.get('/Home/SignIn', function (data) { $('.content').html(data); }); }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function(){ $("#myDialogContents").html(PageState.CachedView);
  });
```

One thing I would watch out for is to clear the text boxes when the cached html is shown unless you want the the username preserved.